# Empty ordered list messes up CSS table layout

Tags: html, css

Why does the the empty unordered list in the first table push the list in the other 'table-cell' down?

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div>
                <ol>
                    <li>an item</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div>
                <ol>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
}

.table-cell > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.table-cell ol {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Full example at http://jsfiddle.net/facboy/7bs4xopg/.  The second table where both lists are populated is how I expected the layout to look

Obviously I could just not have the empty `<ol>` and the effect would be the same, but I'm curious as to the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how baselines in table cells are calculated depending on whether or not they have inline content. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout) sums it up very nicely:

> The baseline of a cell is the baseline of the first in-flow [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box) in the cell, or the first in-flow table-row in the cell, whichever comes first. If there is no such line box or table-row, the baseline is the bottom of content edge of the cell box.

Since your table cell as well as all of its descendants has no text, it generates no line boxes. The only other boxes in your empty cell are the block boxes generated by the inner `<div>` and the `<ol>` respectively. The bottom of the outermost of these boxes becomes the baseline.

This baseline is then aligned with the text in the other cell without actually affecting the interior layout of that cell. This causes that cell to be pushed down.

Note that not having the `<ol>` alone will not produce the desired effect as the inner `<div>` will still hijack the table cell's baseline. The cell must be completely empty, or at the very least, its contents must have zero height.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because the vertical-alignment of your cells is set by default to `baseline` (as you can see from green line on the screenshot)

[image]

thus add a `vertical-align: top` to `.table-cell`

```
.table-cell {
   ...
   vertical-align: top;  
}
```

Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/b86qyzc5/

Comment: Thanks also, I liked the reference to the spec in BoltClock's answer though.